# Inheritance with static classes

Tags: c#, oop, static, abstract-class

I don't know whether this question will make sense or if it's a naive question, but I haven't been able to find a satisfactory answer.

I would like to be able to share code across multiple static classes. Is there an "equivalent" of an abstract base class for static classes (i.e. can I have one static class inherit from another one)? If not, why not? Is there another way of sharing code across multiple static classes in a manner analogous to what you do with an abstract base class?

Also, how does a static class compare to a "sealed" class?

Comment: What exactly _is_ your question? `sealed` classes cannot be inherited, that's the whole reason for the `sealed` keyword to exist.

Comment: A `sealed` class is, by definition a class from which you cannot inherit. What exactly is your question?

Comment: "The sealed modifier prevents other classes from inheriting from it" https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/88c54tsw.aspx Whereas an "abstract class must be inherited by a class that provides an implementation of the abstract methods or properties".

Comment: i think i have clarified the question, in place of static i typed sealed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're quite right. Reflection will show that a `static` class is both `abstract` and `sealed`:

```
  public static class MyStaticTest {
  }

  ...

  // I'm abstract
  Console.WriteLine(typeof(MyStaticTest).IsAbstract ? "I'm abstract" : "");
```

and that's why you can't create an instance (compile time error): `new MyStaticTest();`. However, reflection will show that any `static` class is `sealed` as well:

```
 // I'm sealed 
 Console.WriteLine(typeof(MyStaticTest).IsSealed ? "I'm sealed" : "");
```

and so you can't inherit from it (compile time error): `public class MyClass: MyStaticTest {..}`. Thus, all you can do with `static` class is to declare `static` members (static fields, properties, methods etc.)

Comment: `any abstract class is sealed one as well` I think you mean static, instead of abstract.

Comment: @Jonesopolis: I'm sorry for typo, any `static` (not `abstact`) class is `sealed` one; need more  coffee

Comment: no need to be sorry, it was a very helpful answer

Comment: I didn't know static classes are both sealed and abstract.  A very helpful answer indeed!

Answer (score 0):

The abstract keyword enables to create classes and class members that are incomplete and must be implemented in a derived class whereas The sealed keyword enables you to prevent the inheritance of a class or certain class members that were previously marked virtual.

I think its complete for Above

Comment: Abstract and Sealed Keyword Plays the main role .